# NPM dependency version marked as *

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I have inherited a codebase, and it has these deps listed:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "*",
    "react-intl": "*",
    "react-redux": "*",
```

Am I correct that this means "grab the latest version of the package" when `npm install` is run? (What about beta and alpha releases?)

Comment: Just type "react" and "*" into https://semver.npmjs.com/ to see. Also https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#x-ranges-12x-1x-12-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the version to '*' will install the latest with `npm install --save` and if already installed you can run `npm update --save` to update to the latest version.

The version must be parseable by node-semver, which is a dependency of npm.
More on version syntax can be found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver